# Python code for reverse Geo-coding using Google API

Tags: python-2.7, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am getting the geo-data in a json file (geo.json) which has the following structure

```
 {"userId":"Geo-data","data":{"mocked":false,"timestamp":1548173963281,"coords":{"speed":0,"heading":0,"accuracy":20.20400047302246,"longitude":88.4048656,"altitude":0,"latitude":22.5757344}}}
```

All I want is to print the place details corresponding to above data and if possible to show it on MAP also.I have tried the following code with geopy

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("22.5757344, 88.4048656")
print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

But the location I am getting is not very accurate. Whereas the same coordinates give good results in https://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html
I also have a Google API key. However, what ever references I found so far are almost like a project themselves and a overkill for a beginner like me. The geopy code was fine but the location accuracy is very poor. Please help.

P.S
I have tried geocoder also as

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.google([45.15, -75.14], method='reverse')
print(g.city)
print(g.state)
print(g.state_long)
print(g.country)
print(g.country_long)
```

However it is printing 'None' in all the cases.

Comment: Don't know why someone has marked it negative. It is not a duplicate and I have tried to explain everything I tried so that someone can help. How else am I suppose to ask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could consider to switch from [OpenStreetMap Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) provider to [Google Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Then, the following example seems returns the address you expect it to:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key=google_key)
locations = geolocator.reverse("22.5757344, 88.4048656")
if locations:
    print(locations[0].address)  # select first location
```

**Result**

```
R-1, GA Block, Sector III, Salt Lake City, Kolkata, West Bengal 700106, India
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly in command line. Anyway to show the same on Map? I have unrestricted Test API.

Comment: with the latest geopy library ( 2.2.0 ) the `geolocator.reverse()` call defaults the `exactly_one=True` argument. Thus the code should be modified to `location = geolocator.reverse("22.5757344, 88.4048656") if location: location.address`

Answer (score 5):

You can try a Python Client for Google Maps Services library that can be found at

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

This is a wrapper library for Google Maps API web service requests developed by Googlers. The code snapshot is the following

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='Add Your Key here')

# Look up an address with reverse geocoding
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((22.5757344, 88.4048656))
```

This code returns address `R-1, GA Block, Sector III, Salt Lake City, Kolkata, West Bengal 700106, India` similar to the result that you can see in Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D22.575734%252C88.404866

For further details have a look at the documentation in github.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It is showing a screen full of information as my API key is unrestricted. I have seen the Github before asking help here, but it was a overkill for a noob like me.